# How to group by on all the columns in data.frame?

Tags: r

I have following `data.frame` in R:

```
  Introvert      Extrovert      Nature       Presence
     0              -1            3             Yes     
     1               3            2             No
     2               5            4             Yes
     1              -2            0             No
```

Now, I want to code the responses in following manner:

```
    3,4 <- Positives
    0,1,2 <- Neutral
    < 0 <- Negatives
```

And then get the count of `Positives`, `Negatives` and `Neutrals` across `Yes` and `No`.
I have 20 columns of responses like the above. How can I do it in simpler code in R?

I am doing it `ifelse` and then `group_by` for every column.

My sample desired dataframe would be:

```
         Introvert_Positive      Introvert_Negative     Introvert_Neutral

  Yes        0                         0                      2
  No         0                         0                      2
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your expected output. I do understand you want to re-encode the responses, but why does your expected output only contain `Introvert_*` columns. What happened to the `Extrovert` and `Nature` responses?

Comment: It will be the same way as `Introvert` in the next columns. `Extrovert_Positive,Extrovert_Negative,Extrovert_Neutral` and so on.

Comment: The fact that your expected output is in fact not your *full* expected output would've been a critical bit of information to include your post... anyway, I've posted a possible solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
library(tidyverse);
df %>%
    gather(key, value, -Presence) %>%
    mutate(bin = cut(
        value,
        breaks = c(-Inf, -1, 2.5, Inf),
        labels = c("Negatives", "Neutral", "Positives"))) %>%
    select(-value) %>%
    unite(col, key, bin, sep = "_") %>%
    count(Presence, col) %>%
    spread(col, n)
## A tibble: 2 x 6
#  Presence Extrovert_Negativ… Extrovert_Positi… Introvert_Neutr… Nature_Neutral
#  <fct>                 <int>             <int>            <int>          <int>
#1 No                        1                 1                2              2
#2 Yes                       1                 1                2             NA
## ... with 1 more variable: Nature_Positives <int>
```

Explanation: We use `cut` with `labels` to re-encode the responses; the rest is a matter of `gather`ing, `unite`ing relevant columns, `count`ing the number of occurrences and `spread`ing from long to wide.

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "Introvert      Extrovert      Nature       Presence
     0              -1            3             Yes
     1               3            2             No
     2               5            4             Yes
     1              -2            0             No", header = T)
```

Comment: Just one small question,how did you recode the response in the code?

Comment: We use `cut` to bin values into categories (bins) with breakpoints defined in your post. We can give specific labels to the different categories with the `labels` argument. Take a look at `?cut` for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun/practice, I created a data.table approach using the workflow of the answer from @MauritsEvers. 
It is ~60% faster than the dplyr-approach (see benchmarks)

### data.table

You can skip the `unite` of columns key and bin, since this can be handled in the same step as casting, when using dcast.

```
df %>% 
  setDT() %>%
  melt( id = 4 ) %>%
  .[, bin := cut( value, 
                  breaks = c(-Inf, -1, 2.5, Inf),
                  labels = c("Negatives", "Neutral", "Positives") )] %>%
  .[, value := NULL] %>%
  .[, .N, by = c("Presence", "variable", "bin")] %>% 
  dcast( Presence ~ variable + bin, value.var = "N")



Presence Introvert_Neutral Extrovert_Negatives Extrovert_Positives Nature_Neutral Nature_Positives
1:       No                 2                   1                   1              2               NA
2:      Yes                 2                   1                   1             NA                2
```

### benchmarks

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  dplyr = {
    df %>%
      gather(key, value, -Presence) %>%
      mutate(bin = cut(
        value,
        breaks = c(-Inf, -1, 2.5, Inf),
        labels = c("Negatives", "Neutral", "Positives"))) %>%
      select(-value) %>%
      unite(col, key, bin, sep = "_") %>%
      count(Presence, col) %>%
      spread(col, n)
  },
  data.table = {
    df %>% 
      setDT() %>%
      melt( id = 4 ) %>%
      .[, bin := cut( value, 
                      breaks = c(-Inf, -1, 2.5, Inf),
                      labels = c("Negatives", "Neutral", "Positives") )] %>%
      .[, value := NULL] %>%
      .[, .N, by = c("Presence", "variable", "bin")] %>% 
      dcast( Presence ~ variable + bin, value.var = "N")
  },
  times = 1000
)

Unit: milliseconds
       expr      min        lq     mean    median        uq      max neval
      dplyr 9.636224 10.083903 10.59597 10.267371 10.458524 26.38649  1000
 data.table 3.458208  3.647401  3.92219  3.835239  3.949568 15.05596  1000
```